# What would be the best way of providing small image selection in an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone

I have a bunch of small png images with about 45 x 45 pixels of size. not really big ones. there are about 40 of them right now.

I want that the user can select one of them as his avatar image. For this, I created an brand new view with an controller class. Now the problem is: How to display all those images to the user? There's no "big view". When the user touches one of them, it's going to be selected and the view switches back to the main view, where he's going to see his selected image. When he touches it, the image selection view will appear again.

So I thought about an table view, but it feels not right. The images have no title to be displayed, so it would be a big waste of screen space.

Any ideas? Should I programmatically generate a grid of UIImageView objects?

Answer (score 2):

A grid is correct.  Think iPhone Photos application.  No need to make a completely new widget though, add multiple image views to table rows, segmenting them.

Answer (score 0):

A grid seems like a good solution as it mirrors the wallpaper ui in settings so the user knows what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in this case would be to use a UIPickerView.  It takes up less screen space, and can be shown on the main screen (just pop up from the bottom, let them pick one, then disappear).